# Hive Query failing

Tags: sql, kotlin, hadoop, hive

I've set up the hive query to run on a job every day and today it's the first day running it failed for me. From what I've got set up I'm not seeing where I went wrong here.

```
fun getFlightStatus(date: LocalDate, flightstatuses: List< flightstatus>): Set<Alert> {
    val flightstatusesString = flightstatuses.joinToString(prefix = "(", postfix = ")", transform = { "'$it'" })
 val query =
        """select passengerID, flightstatus, partition_date from(
           |select distinct $flightTable.passengerID, $flightTable.flightstatus, $flightTable.partition_date
           |from $flightTable
           |where $flightTable.flightstatus in $flightstatusesString and $flightTable.partition_date = Date('$date')
           |)""".trimMargin()

    return hiveTemplate.execute(customCallback(query) { resultSet -> resultSet.toAlert() })
        .also { logger.info("<<< flights.getFlightStatus($date, $statuses)") }.toSet()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Subquery in Hive should have an alias.

```
select ... from (select ....) s --here s is an alias
```

Comment: i did not want a subquery anything. I just want to grab the passengerID, flightstatus, partition_date

Comment: If you do not want subquery, then remove it somehow. But now there is a subquery `select from (select ) ` without an alias.  Also check the variable name $statusString

Comment: `val query =
        """select distinct $flightTable.passengerID, $flightTable.flightstatus, $flightTable.partition_date from(
           |from $flightTable
           |where $flightTable.flightstatus in $flightstatusesString and $flightTable.partition_date = Date('$date')
           |)""".trimMargin() `

is what I have now but I've got two froms. are there any examples you could link me?

Comment: @AnthonyEdwardsStan As I already said, your query contains a subquery without alias. Alias is a mandatory.  This is your subquery: ( |from $flightTable |where $flightTable.flightstatus in $flightstatusesString and $flightTable.partition_date = Date('$date') |)   add alias after it: ( |from $flightTable |where $flightTable.flightstatus in $flightstatusesString and $flightTable.partition_date = Date('$date') |) s

Comment: I removed the subquery because I'm only working within one table I don't think it's needed.